# Display category with its products list (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, category

I am trying to display the category with its products list below format on magento version 2.4.3.

1 Category A

SKU - Product Name 1

SKU - Product Name 2

2 Category B

SKU - Product Name 1

SKU - Product Name 2

File :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Fedex\CategoryList\Block;

class Categories extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface
     */
    private $categoryManagement;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface $categoryManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface $categoryManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->categoryManagement = $categoryManagement;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Category Tree by Category ID
     */
    public function getCategoryTree()
    {
        $rootCategoryId = 3;
        try {
            $categoryTree = $this->categoryManagement->getTree($rootCategoryId);
            return $categoryTree;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new \Exception($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It returns category data not product data, need advice on how it can be displayed.

Comment: any  thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this blog : https://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-how-to-call-category-collection-on-home-page

Thanks.